# How to tar a directory

Tags: python-3.x, linux-kernel, google-colaboratory

I want to tar two directories I have downloaded into my program. I am working in Colab environment similar to tensorflow. But when i run the following commands

```
!tar -zxf ./RoadDamageDataset.tar.gz
!tar -zxf ./trainedModels.tar.gz
```

I get this type of error

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So far I have tried to run the above commands without `-` but it doesn't work.
Also somewhere I have read that maybe the files are not downloaded properly so I have double checked the files and again downloaded for two times but still this error remains.

Can anyone here help me with this kind of problem as I have no idea with how to deal with `tar`.

Thank you

Comment: Cross check the checksum `md5sum` or `sha*` from the source of download with the downloaded file.

Comment: Mr. Parthiban I'm new to work in the envirment of colab/tensor flow. kindly elaborate as I dont know how to check the checksum `md5sum` u have mentioned  -Rakeh

Comment: I am not sure about the environment. But if you have `md5sum` command, just execute as `md5sum <name of the downloaded file>` and cross check the value from the source of download

Comment: I have tried to run the command but its not executing instead of getting `error` every time

Comment: Please share a notebook that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sir I'm using Colab and double checked it on jupyter notebook also